# Converting Excel cells to time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I'm trying to convert a list of time strings((?)not sure, although type (list[1]) says str), to timedate (or any other alternative if something else is better).

I want to sum up these times if a certain condition is met. This is what I got so far:

```
import os
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx')
read_file2 = read_file['Duration']

uren_lijst = []

for row in read_file2:
    for row in read_file2:
    uren_lijst.append(row)
```

I already tried using the 'pd.to_datetime' method, but this seems to create timestamps and I only neet the hours and I am not interested in the date itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

First convert it to a `datetime` column. Then extract `hour` from it.

```
read_file['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(read_file['Duration'])
hours = read_file['Duration'].dt.hour
```

After OP's comment:

```
time = read_file['Duration'].dt.time
```

Comment: This almost works, except that the minutes are also necessary. So I need the sum of the time after the last complete hour aswell.

Comment: Can you share the exact output that you need?

Comment: The 'dt.time' function did the job, I was able to find this thank to your 'dt.hour' function. Thanks a lot!